# Can I have a placeholder for a variable and use queues at the same time?

Tags: python-3.x, queue, tensorflow, placeholder

for feeding my network data in tensorflow I'm using  `tf.train.batch` but I also want to 'feed' the training with a predefined learning rate. I have a function `_getLearningRate` that creates a list o values I want to use for learning rate, in which I make sure the type of elements is float32. But I am getting an error

```
W tensorflow/core/framework/op_kernel.cc:940] Invalid argument: You must feed a value for placeholder tensor 'Placeholder' with dtype float
     [[Node: Placeholder = Placeholder[dtype=DT_FLOAT, shape=[], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/gpu:0"]()]]
```

So I am wondering can this be because I process a couple of batches at the same time so that the first one is being indeed fed with lr value but others in a queue are just empty. Or maybe there is another reason for this? 
My code looks like this:

```
`def launch_net():
  with tf.Graph().as_default(): 
    global_step = tf.Variable(0,trainable = False)
    lr = tf.placeholder(tf.float32)
    input_images = inputEKG.data
    input_labels = inputEKG.labels
    # queue runner slicing input tensors into single examples
    image, label = tf.train.slice_input_producer(
          [input_images, input_labels], num_epochs=args.num_epochs)
    label = tf.cast(label, tf.int32)
    # queue runner creates batches
    images, labels = tf.train.batch([image, label], batch_size=args.bsize) 

    logits = inference(images, args, True)

    total_loss = loss(logits, labels, args)

    train_op = train(total_loss, global_step, args, lr)

    saver = tf.train.Saver(tf.all_variables(),max_to_keep=10)
    summary_op = tf.merge_all_summaries()
    init  = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_variables(), tf.initialize_local_variables())
    sess = tf.Session()

    sess.run(init)
    summary_writer = tf.train.SummaryWriter(args.train_dir, sess.graph)

    coord = tf.train.Coordinator()
    threads = tf.train.start_queue_runners(sess=sess, coord=coord)

    try:
      while not coord.should_stop(): 

        global_step_value = sess.run(global_step)
        _, loss_value = sess.run([logits,total_loss])

        lr_ = _getLearningRate(global_step_value, args)

        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict={lr: lr_})
`
```

It started working when I fed the latter `sess.run` with `feed_dict={lr: lr_}`, so it had nothing to do with the queues. Still don't quite understand why it worked.

Comment: Your `lr` is a placeholder, and `total_loss` depends on it, so you have to feed `lr` whenever you eval `total_loss`